# How to approach for developing multiplayer (networked) video game in .NET

Tags: c#, design-patterns

i'm trying to develop a simple multiplayer video game (2d) in C#, SDL.NET and obviously .NET. 
Two, or more  player over internet, can control a car (class CAR) who move on the screen with X and Y. 
One PC is the server, others are client.

So, i think "The only value to 'pass' between Players are the value of variables X, Y, and someother 'state' variable". 
The graphics and other "stuff" must be accomplished from single client. 
What i need, i think, is only the Socket Class.

Does this approach is correct ?
Someother advice or examples to show me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It might be worthwhile to cross post this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a high level answer but your question is pretty high level as well.

I'd suggest that the best place to start would be with the Microsoft DirectX website which covers all sorts of APIs and examples relating to implementing games. There's native support for drawing as well as the network libraries required for multiplayer interaction.

Here' a [getting started guide on the Microsoft DirectX website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/default.aspx)

There also other alternatives. [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) is a nice framework which allows you to develop simulatenously for desktop, web and mobile such as iPhone and Android.